# Как запустить composer install на ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu, composer

Установил гит, с клонировал репозиторий своего сайта с гит. Установил компойзер, установил php , запускаю composer install выдает вот такие ошибки, подскажите как исправить. Пытался поставить facebook/webdriver отдельно ругается.

> ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-Notebook:/var/www/yii/crm_2.3$ sudo composer install
>   Do not run Composer as root/super user! See
>   https://getcomposer.org/root for details Loading composer repositories
>   with package information Installing dependencies (including
>   require-dev) from lock file Your requirements could not be resolved to
>   an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for facebook/webdriver 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.4.1].
>       - facebook/webdriver 1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
>    Problem 2
>       - facebook/webdriver 1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
>       - codeception/codeception 2.3.3 requires facebook/webdriver >=1.0.1 <2.0 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.4.1].
>       - Installation request for codeception/codeception 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.3.3].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zmq.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить команду с правами суперпользователя - `sudo composer install`. Система попросит ввести пароль, но при вводе не будет его отображать. Это нормально. Введите пароль и нажмите enter

Comment: плюс curl в PHP надо включить в конфигах. если нет, поставить `sudo apt install php7.0-curl`

Comment: @alvoro , сделал как вы сказали и то что Pusher предложил, исправил описание т.к длинный текст. В итоге все так же ругается на facebook/webdriver

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. В итоге мне надо было только в глобальном композере поставить php composer.phar require facebook/webdriver он ругался что нету расширения zip у php я на примере с curl поставил его , потом уже сам фейсбуквебдрайвер, потом уже в проекте через судо запустил и началось скачивание.